# QScriptValue::toVariant but no fromVariant?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

[QScriptValue::toVariant](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qscriptvalue.html#toVariant) can turn basic string and number types, as well as arrays and objects (associative arrays), into a QVariant.

There doesn't seem to be any corresponding way to construct a QScriptValue from a QVariant.

Is it hiding, or missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscriptengine.html#newVariant

> **QScriptValue QScriptEngine::newVariant(const QVariant & value)**
>
> Creates a Qt Script object holding the given variant value.
>
> If a default prototype has been registered with the meta type id of
>   value, then the prototype of the created object will be that
>   prototype; otherwise, the prototype will be the Object prototype
>   object.

Comment: it's a good idea to quote the text in the answer. That makes it easy to find the information even if the link is dead (as it was). I've now updated the link and quoted the text.